# Bash: Iterate through array and use as options in a case statement

Tags: bash

I'm trying to loop through an array and set options for an interactive selection. Can't seem to figure out the correct syntax and/or way of doing this. Here's what I have, so far.

```
array=(red blue green yellow)
PS3='Select option: '
echo "Options are $array"

select opt in "${array[@]}"
do
  case $opt in
    for c in "${array[@]}" do
      export COLOR="${array[$c]}"
      break
      ;;
    done
  esac
done
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong with the syntax or approach, but I'm getting the following error:

```
syntax error near unexpected token `c'
```

Expected behavior would be:

```
Select choice:
1) red
2) blue
3) green
4) yellow
```

Comment: Why not just `select opt in "${array[@}"; do export COLOR="$opt"; break; done`? Why do you iterate over the array the second time? Is there a reason? You already now the chosen option, it's in `opt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `for` loop or `case`. The value of `$opt` is the color they selected.

```
select opt in "${array[@]}"
do
  if [ "$opt" ]
  then export COLOR="$opt"; break
  fi
done
```